# Transform selector to style in CSS

Tags: html, css

I get this element when I copy the selector on my console

```css
#feed-body > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.description > span > span.image > img
```

If I want to style or overwrite the styling of img with !important what would be the CSS?

I tried

```css
span.image img {width:100% !important}
```

but is not working (the default is `max-width: 84px` which I want to change).

I also tried with max-width: 300px !important but no results.

Am I giving style to the wrong class or is something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: open your browser's debugger to inspect that element (the `img`), check if your css rule is being applied but overridden by something else. If it s not being applied then most probably you need to re-define your selector. I think it is getting overridden somewhere.

Comment: But first of all i want to know if span.image img is the right class to style. Am i right? Should i maybe include the div in my styling?

Comment: Your selector is fine as it is. `span.image > img` is used when `img` is a direct children of `span.image`, the way you write it should also work but it most probably is overridden.

Comment: No overwriting because when i uncheck max-width 84px in console image goes 100%. So my styling works but can't overwrite the existing one

Comment: Can you post the `CSS` class (or classes e.g. `div.description > span > span.image > img, div.myotherclass img,...`) as seen in your debugger where 84px is written? Use the same selector to override it.

Comment: Meaning if in debugger you see that `max-width: 84px` belongs to `feed-body > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.description > span > span.image > img` then use that selector  to override it.

Comment: That's what i thought also but i need help! How can i transform that in css? How can i use div:nth-child(1) as part of css ? As it is?

Comment: Yes use the exact selector that is used when you inspect the `img` in your browser's debugger in Elements, Styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect your page and see in the 'style' section if there is another rule overwriting this rule.

Also, `max-width` could limit your `width` rule, so you may need to overwrite both:

```
width: 100% !important; max-width: initial !important;
```

Comment: I'm afraid i'm giving style to the wrong class because when i apply your suggestion (or even mine) to span.image img i see no result in the console at all. Should i maybe include the div in my styling? And no overwriting because when i uncheck max-width 84px image goes 100%. So my styling works but cant overwrite the existing one.

Comment: i mean when i uncheck in console. sorry

Comment: max-width 84px has an `!important`? You may define a more specific selector than the original to make sure your style is the preffered one (eg. using an ID in the element you need to overwrite styles)

Comment: max-width 84px has no !important and i tried the only ID i see there #feed-body but not working

Comment: could you post a capture of the style inspection window for that element to get a better look?

Comment: Image in the post now

Comment: Thank you, It would be better to show the inspection filtered by 'width' (in the small search box) to see only styles related to this property

Comment: Filtered by width in post now. There is no other width hidden in image below.